# What happened do Swiping in UWP?

Tags: uwp, gesture

I'm moving my code from Windows 8.1 (MDL) to Windows 10 (UWP).  In MDL you could swipe with your finger in the opposite direction of scrolling and it would select the item in a ListView.  Oddly, it still works with the mouse, but not on my Surface with a finger gesture.  Any ideas where this functionality went to and how to reacquire the ability to select with a finger gesture?

Comment: Not clear what MDL is, could you describe your issue with more details? What is the effect you want? I see the [SwipeControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/swipe) provides access to contextual commands through touch interactions, do you mean it works with mouse? Please help me understand your question.

Comment: MDL is Microsoft Design Language, basically Windows 8.1.  The effect is swiping left (opposite the direction of scroll) to select an item.  The IsSwipeEnabled allowed for this action in Windows 8.1.  The action still works in UWP (Windows 10) when you use a mouse, but for some unexplained reason, the same action of swiping a finger does nothing.

Comment: Could you provide a simple sample to let me see your issue and talk at the same direction?

Answer (score 1):

The new templates of UWP `ListView` controls don't use this gesture anymore, as there were discoverability issues for users, who didn't know how to select. You could probably implement this again manually using `ScrollViewer` behind the list view items and watching for its scroll position. However, the general recommendation is to handle this differently on UWP.

UWP apps usually have a command bar button that switches the list from click mode to selection mode and then check boxes are shown on individual items. Usually you can also move to this mode by tap-and-holding an item.

See the UWP OneDrive app for an example of how apps wit multi-select tend to behave.

Comment: Any idea why the gesture works for mice but not for touches?

Comment: Does it have the same behaviour? As in - does the list view item actually "move" when you flick with the mouse? Or could you post the XAML you use so that I can try myself?

Comment: Yes, the view item actually animates a flick when you use the mouse button.  There's a different animation when you press with your finger.  Move the mouse button to the left and the item is selected.  Move the finger to the left and nothing. How can I post the code without posting an answer?

Comment: Interesting, so it seems some of the behaviour got migrated as part of the Windows 8.1 template. You can click "edit" under your question to add some text there.